# Bootstrap 3 Media Queries: Breakpoint occuring at odd dimensions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I'm an amateur developer both in Bootstrap and Media Queries.

I am trying to making the navigation bar of a Bootstrapped site responsive with slight customization. I am running into issues when I resize the browser.

At normal dimensions, The site looks something like this:

[image]
However, there is a breakpoint at 1130 px ( Very Odd number? Why!) and the navigation bar looks like this:
[image]

As you see, the width of the navigation bar doubles and the user icon is displaced to the next line.
When we reduce the size further, the navigation bar remains like this till 1005px:
[image]
The next breakpoint is at 1004px, when the search box comes to the extreme left:
[image]

This remains like this till 960px:

[image]

At 959px, The design changes CSS again:

[image]

At 881px, The design keeps the same CSS:
[image]

CSS again changes at 880px:
[image]

Until finally coming to the last breakpoint at 767px, after which the site remains same:

[image]

I dont understand why at 1130px, 1004px, 959px and 880px there is such an awkward displacement of items.

What should I do:

1. that at 1130px, the user icon does not spill to the next line?
2. From 960px to 1004px, the search bar and the user icon are not displaced to the next line.
3. at 880px, The user icon does not displace to the next line.

I want that at all times, the search bar and the user icon should be inline with the Logo. How should I attain that?

I'll be glad if someone can take the pain and tell why the breaking is happening at such odd numbers.

This is the following media query that was written in styles.css:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}

@media(min-width:960px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: 250px;
    }
}
```

The Site is [up here](https://ae9b21d2de5fe39e92f83abce83fb380f30ab420.googledrive.com/host/0B0byAC8kZZPhQTN1MG5KZVZoWk0/) and the HTML/CSS/Bootstrap files [are here](https://drive.google.com/#folders/0B0byAC8kZZPhQTN1MG5KZVZoWk0).

Comment: Check the zoom level of your browser.  Make sure it's at default 100% and not zoomed in or zoomed out at all.

Comment: can i change the breakpoints that u used???

Comment: user3426358 please do *not* do what @Harsh said in a comment below the answers. Please keep your code in the question so it can help others.

Comment: @AndrewBarber what i meant was to make a jsfiddle instead of the complete code that needs to be downloaded n tried..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your media queries to this and it is going to work

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 880px){
    .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding: 30px 5px !important;
    }
    .navbar-nav{
        margin-left:5px;
    }

}

@media(min-width:960px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        margin-left: 120px;
    }
    .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding: 30px 15px !important;
    }
}
```